# Test a cell on a Google Sheet and write to that row

Tags: python, python-3.x, drive

I've got a Google Sheet with students names (columns `A` and `B`) and some value in the column next to it (column `C`). I'd like to test each value in turn and write to that row's (column `D`) if the test resolves to `True`.

My code so far:

```
from __future__ import print_function
import httplib2
import os
from apiclient import discovery
from oauth2client import client
from oauth2client import tools
from oauth2client.file import Storage

# Don't know what this is for
try:
    import argparse
    flags = argparse.ArgumentParser(parents=[tools.argparser]).parse_args()
except ImportError:
    flags = None

# If modifying these scopes, delete your previously saved credentials
# at ~/.credentials/sheets.googleapis.com-python-quickstart.json
SCOPES = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets.readonly'
CLIENT_SECRET_FILE = 'client_secret.json'
APPLICATION_NAME = 'Google Sheets API'

# just copied code from Google's Dev guide
def get_credentials():
    """Gets valid user credentials from storage.

    If nothing has been stored, or if the stored credentials are invalid,
    the OAuth2 flow is completed to obtain the new credentials.

    Returns:
        Credentials, the obtained credential.
    """
    home_dir = os.path.expanduser('~')
    credential_dir = os.path.join(home_dir, '.credentials')
    if not os.path.exists(credential_dir):
        os.makedirs(credential_dir)
    credential_path = os.path.join(credential_dir,
                                   'sheets.googleapis.com-python-quickstart.json')

    store = Storage(credential_path)
    credentials = store.get()
    if not credentials or credentials.invalid:
        flow = client.flow_from_clientsecrets(CLIENT_SECRET_FILE, SCOPES)
        flow.user_agent = APPLICATION_NAME
        if flags:
            credentials = tools.run_flow(flow, store, flags)
        else: # Needed only for compatibility with Python 2.6
            credentials = tools.run(flow, store)
        print('Storing credentials to ' + credential_path)
    return credentials

# PROBLEM IS IN THIS METHOD
def main():
    # Hope Google doesn't change all this API stuff and make us redo:
    credentials = get_credentials()
    http = credentials.authorize(httplib2.Http())
    discoveryUrl = ('https://sheets.googleapis.com/$discovery/rest?'
                    'version=v4')
    service = discovery.build('sheets', 'v4', http=http,
                              discoveryServiceUrl=discoveryUrl)
    # Fake URI of our sheet
    spreadsheetId = '5lksdfusdlfkjkj886kJUNKssdff'

    # retrieve data works
    rangeName = 'Sheet1!A2:D70'
    result = service.spreadsheets().values().get(
        spreadsheetId=spreadsheetId, range=rangeName).execute()
    values = result.get('values', [])

    if not values:
        print('No data found.')
    else:
        for row in values:
            print('Checking on: %s %s' % (row[0], row[1]))
            # PROBLEM... can't seem 
            if row[2] == "Some arbitrary condition":
                # Even trying to hardcode a range doesn't work 
                # I'd like to reference the coordinates of this row 
                result = service.spreadsheets().values().update(
                    spreadsheetId=spreadsheetId, range='Sheet1!D64',
                    body="can you see me?").execute()
                print(result)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Can you provide the stacktrace/error printout you're getting?

Comment: `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/myUsername/PycharmProjects/pitendance/main.py", line 91, in <module>
    main()
  File "/Users/myUsername/PycharmProjects/pitendance/main.py", line 77, in main
    print('Checking on: %s %s' % (row[0], row[1]))
IndexError: list index out of range`

Comment: Try debugging that last for loop in the main function. An `IndexError` indicates that you're trying to access an item from the `row` list that isn't there. Try printing the row before the loop to see if it gives what you're expecting.

Comment: The weird thing is that the output is successful in the console, I see all the names in the first two columns. Something's goofy about my `result = service.spreadsheets().values().update(
                    spreadsheetId=spreadsheetId, range='Sheet1!D64',
                    body="can you see me?").execute()`